# IOException in Android application

Tags: android, inputstream, readline, bufferedreader

I have just started with Android development, and facing one issue in the android application.

When application tries to read the data from file (raw resources), it throws IOException on readLine() function. code is as below:

```
final Resources resources = m_ApplicationContext.getResources();
InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.datafile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
   inputStream));

try {
 String line;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

the reader.readLine() function is throwing the exception. Do I need to mention any kind of additional permission for reading the file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the content of the IOException?  Usually it will give you an idea of what the problem is.  Otherwise just an IOException is pretty vague

Comment: Hi Chris, actually i am not getting any details with the exception. Not even the stack trace for this.

Comment: it is only giving details as "IOException in class".
I put watch on "reader.readLine()", it tells me the exception is routed from AssetManager class.

Comment: Hmm, can you put an exception.printStackTrace() in your `catch` block and get the exception details that way?  It would be very helpful to know what the exception actually states.

Comment: StackTrace was pointing to AssetManager class, but anyways I got something interesting. It is giving problem for large files, original file size was more than 1MB. When tried with small file it did work well. I guess i need to split the file into multiple chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. The problem seems to be that you can only read files with up to 1MB

see here
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e3765c112d112f24